# what language do I use with AudioKit?

Tags: c++, swift, audiokit

Hi is audioKit an API where you just use swift or can I use c++ as well. asking because I'm teaching myself c++ and want to know if I should also learn swift just to use AudioKit. On the website it says AudioKit is built using c++,swift, and c. Am I suppose to know all three? sorry I'm new to programming.

Comment: You can use most C libraries from non-C languages (with reasonable support for loading native libraries, which is generally considered something necessary for a language to be taken seriously these days). A wrapper that lets you do so *easily* is something you'll tend to see referred to as language "bindings". AudioKit comes with explicitly supported bindings for Swift, so you can use Swift to access all the functionality, including functionality written in C or C++, out-of-the-box.

Comment: The set of tool a programming language comes with to let you use libraries written in other languages, btw, is called a "foreign function interface", often shortened to "FFI". Using a FFI directly is typically less pleasant than going through a wrapper or set of bindings built-to-task, but a good FFI makes building wrappers *easy*.

Comment: ...knowing all three languages is going to be helpful if you want to *contribute to* AudioKit or debug issues with its code; not so much if you're just interacting with it as a user.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your comments add up to an excellent answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just Swift with AudioKit if you are only using the baked-in goodies.

If you want to write your own audio render block, then you cannot do that in Swift (yet). Most developers use C++ or C in the render block.